# How to Android Studio RC2 Build Tools Error

Tags: android

Android Studio RC2 update after error...
Was using the existing Android Studio 0.14.0

app install build only an error ,  There is no error in the gradle build!

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
 com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
 /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/sdk/build-tools/21.1.1/dx 
 --dex --no-optimize      --  output /Users/..../app/build/intermediates/dex/debug 
 --input-     list=/Users/.../app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
   Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/io/CopyUtils;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

app/build.gradle

```
    android {
     compileSdkVersion 21
     buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com......"
         minSdkVersion 10
         targetSdkVersion 21
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"

         buildTypes {
                 release {
                 minifyEnabled false
                 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

         .
         .
         .
```

gradle version

```
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc1'
```

Android SDK install Build toosl

19.0.x ~ 2.1.1

thk..

Comment: What are your dependencies? The "Multiple dex files define" error comes up when more than one dependency is requiring the same package, but a different version of that package.

Comment: Ray, have you solved your issue, could you post an answer?

Comment: I get this error after adding   dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    } in app build.gradle. But still no idea how to solve this.